# How can I handle SIGINT in Apple M1 assembly code?

Tags: assembly, arm, apple-m1, armv8

I am trying to learn assembly for the Apple M1. I want to write a program that goes into an infinite loop and then exits with status 123 when control-c is pressed. I have written the following program:

```
// foo.s
.align 2
.text
.global _main

_main:
  mov x0, #2
  adrp x1, sigint_handler@page
  add x1, x1, sigint_handler@pageoff
  mov x2, #0
  mov x8, 0x8c
  svc 0

loop:
  b loop

sigint_handler:
  mov x0, #123
  mov x16, #1
  svc 0
```

It can be assembled with:

```
as foo.s -arch arm64 -o foo.o
ld -arch arm64 -syslibroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -lSystem -o foo foo.o
```

And run with:

```
./foo
```

When I press control-c, the program exits with status 130:

```
echo $?
130
```

I was expecting a status code of 123 because of the sigint_handler.

I don't think I'm registering the sigint_handler correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

**Edit:**

After more trying based on Nate's comments, I now have this code:

```
.align 2

.data
nsa: .skip 24

.text
.global _main

_main:
  // Populate the __sigaction nsa struct:
  // https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1504.3.12/bsd/sys/signal.h.auto.html

  adrp x0, nsa@page
  add x0, x0, nsa@pageoff

  adrp x1, sigint_handler@page
  add x1, x1, sigint_handler@pageoff
  str x1, [x0, #0]

  // I'm not sure what to do here:
  mov x1, #0
  str x1, [x0, #8]
  str x1, [x0, #16]

  // Make service call 46:
  // int sigaction(int signum, struct __sigaction *nsa, struct sigaction *osa);
  // https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1504.3.12/bsd/kern/syscalls.master

  mov x0, #2 // SIGINT
  adrp x1, nsa@page
  add x1, x1, nsa@pageoff
  mov x2, #0 // NULL
  mov x16, #46
  svc 0

loop:
  b loop

sigint_handler:
  mov x0, #123
  mov x16, #1
  svc 0
```

I'm trying to build a `__sigaction *nsa` struct so that I can make a valid sigaction service call. This isn't working and I get a segmentation fault when I control-c. I'm not really sure of the sizeof this struct and how to populate its fields correctly.

Comment: Run it through whatever is the macos equivalent of strace.

Comment: Where did you get 0x8c as the system call number for `signal`?

Comment: If https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1504.3.12/bsd/kern/syscalls.master is correct then 0x8c (decimal 140) is `adjtime`.  There isn't a system call for `signal` so you will need to use `sigaction` instead, system call 46, and construct your own `struct sigaction`.

Comment: Also, does the system call number go in x8 or x16?  Your code is inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks @NateEldredge for pointing me in the right direction. x16 is the correct register for service calls. I've edited my post to include my latest attempt based on digging around in the header files.

Comment: Looking more, this is kind of complicated.  You actually have to pass a pointer to a `struct __sigaction`, which includes an extra `sa_tramp` function pointer member whose semantics are not completely clear.  The standard library passes a pointer to some function called `sigtramp`

Comment: It also appears that MacOS code uses `svc 0x80` instead of `svc 0` though I don't know if it actually matters.  And it sets bit 0x400 in `sa_flags` which is undocumented.

Comment: svc 0 seems to work for other service calls, e.g. exit and print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using this relatively simple code:

```
.align 2
.text
.global _main

_main:
  mov x0, #2
  adrp x1, sigint_handler@page
  add x1, x1, sigint_handler@pageoff
  bl _signal

loop:
  b loop

sigint_handler:
  mov x0, #123
  mov x16, #1
  svc 0
```

I achieved this by starting with a simple C program:

```
// foo.c
#include <signal.h>

void handler(int signal) {}

void main(void) {
  signal(SIGINT, handler);
}
```

Then I used gcc to output assembly:

```
gcc -S -o foo.s foo.c
```

Which produced the following:

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .build_version macos, 13, 0 sdk_version 13, 3
    .globl  _handler                        ; -- Begin function handler
    .p2align    2
_handler:                               ; @handler
    .cfi_startproc
; %bb.0:
    sub sp, sp, #16
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    str w0, [sp, #12]
    add sp, sp, #16
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
                                        ; -- End function
    .globl  _main                           ; -- Begin function main
    .p2align    2
_main:                                  ; @main
    .cfi_startproc
; %bb.0:
    stp x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!           ; 16-byte Folded Spill
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    mov x29, sp
    .cfi_def_cfa w29, 16
    .cfi_offset w30, -8
    .cfi_offset w29, -16
    mov w0, #2
    adrp    x1, _handler@PAGE
    add x1, x1, _handler@PAGEOFF
    bl  _signal
    ldp x29, x30, [sp], #16             ; 16-byte Folded Reload
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
                                        ; -- End function
.subsections_via_symbols
```

I then picked out the lines that register the signal handler. I'm not sure where _signal comes from - I presume it's built into the macOS assembler. If anyone can explain that part, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: `_signal` is a libc function.  You are calling into the libc.